# Prestashop - How to get a specific sub category using parent category id

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am new to PrestaShop. I am trying to get an array of sub-categories using parent category id, so I can refer to the different sub-category in different circumstances. 
Actually, I want to place an if statement in a foreach loop and check if its the first iteration of the loop then grab the link of 1st sub-category enlisted and if it's 2nd iteration then grab the link of 2nd sub-category and so on. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!
and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get first level children:

```
$subcategories = Category::getChildren($id_parent, $id_lang);
```

to loop through:

```
foreach($subcategories as $category) {
  echo $category['name'];
}
```

Comment: {$link->getCategoryLink($subcategory.id_category, $subcategory.link_rewrite)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
this is what I am trying to edit to check what is its id

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop 1.6 has getSubCategories function in category class. You should make new category object and use this function on it.

```
/**
 * Return current category childs
 *
 * @param int $id_lang Language ID
 * @param bool $active return only active categories
 * @return array Categories
 */

//public function getSubCategories($id_lang, $active = true)

$this->category = new Category($id_category, $this->context->language->id);

$subcategories = $this->category->getSubCategories($this->context->language->id);
```